# Is it possible to set the text or innerText of a hyper link using `setAttribute`

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically convert my descriptive JSON object into HTML. This is no easy task but since it's only to be used for a small project and a small team, it suits our needs.

This means, the JSON object could look like

```
'element': {
            'href': '#03',
            'text': 'link',
            'myUniqueTag' : 'a'
        }
```

This means I can use `myUniqueTag` and understand I'm dealing the type `a`. This works fine.

The issue I have is setting the value of the text, which is

```
<a href="blah">How do I set this bit</a>
```

This is what I've tried

```
one.text = "Hello world";                           //works
two.innerText = "Hello world";                      //works
three.setAttribute("text", "Hello world");          //fails
four.setAttribute("innerText", "Hello world");      //fails
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3xuovvm/)

For my situation, I have to use setAttributes. My question is, am I missing something or is it not possible to set the text via `setAttribute()`

Please note, I'm using vanilla JavaScript only (no JQuery or framework).

Comment: Ah... I see. But it works @CBroe? Why say it makes no sense? Until now, I would have thought both were doing the same thing via different syntax but it appears they actually do different things behind the scenes in the land of JavaScript

Comment: Find the element from the DOM you want to set the text on. Create a DOM Text element. And then use addChildNode to set the Text Node onto the Parent.

Comment: Right, I understand.

Comment: Well you *can* use setAttribute if you really have to, but it's not the right approach anyway.

Comment: @dfsq why do you feel `setAttribute` is not the right approach?

Comment: Because while you can use setAttribute to change inner text the right way to do it is to just set textContent property.

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can use setAttribute to set the text, however you need to precise witch attribute you set. In your example "text" and "innerText" are not html attribute.

for example :

**JS:**

```
var b = document.createElement('button'); 
b.setAttribute('content', 'test content'); 
b.setAttribute('class', 'btn'); 
b.innerHTML = 'test value';

var wrapper = document.getElementById("divWrapper");
wrapper.appendChild(b);
```

**Looks like this in the DOM:**

```
<div id="divWrapper">
    <button content="test content" class="btn">test value</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So `obj.someProperty ===` is different to `obj.setAttribute("someProperty"` ?

Comment: No, both method can do the same think but with setAtribbute you can add an HTML attribute like style, width, class, value...
innerText is NOT an html attribute

Comment: Are you saying setAttribute only adds attributes and can't append children?

Comment: Wrong, `obj.someProperty = value` is absolutely not the same as `obj.setAttribute("someProperty", value)`. This answer doesn't answer the question how to use `setAttribute` to set innerText.